# maximum number of the threads created by a process

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling

This might look weird but I'm trying to analyze an old `C++` code in our company.
It's a highly multi-threaded code that insanely creates and destroys threads.

For some reasons, I'm interested in **the maximum number of the threads** that the process creates during its life time.

Let's *assume* that the process's behavior is deterministic.
How can I count the maximum number of the threads created by a process?

My environment: Windows/VS2010

Comment: Are threads created by calling `CreateThread` in code? By "maximum number of threads" you mean concurrent or total number during lifetime?

Comment: I didn't look but I guess so. I mean concurrent.

Comment: Watch Task Manager thread count for the process?

Comment: If you can recompile the source, then you can add a couple of functions and a macro to count exactly. If you cannot and it's just an executable, then you can write a program to take a series of snapshots and enumerate current threads for the process. But the maximum number might not be exact if the process creates and kills threads rapidly.

Comment: Perfmon, perhaps? There's a "thread count" counter. Performance data is also available programmatically, if you want more sophisticated analysis than what Perfmon provides out of the box.